# Bitcoin price oracle

Tags: bitcoin, oracles

Are there any oracles available for Bitcoin price? I'd like to do a currency conversion math inside the smart contract code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an updated answer here since this question comes up on searches a lot.  You have three options for the BTC/USD: wbtc/usdc uni pool, a LINK contract that puts it on chain, or Tellor which allows you to request that an update (or stake and update it yourself)

Here's an example with Tellor that pulls the BTC price: https://github.com/tellor-io/sampleUsingTellor

Comment: Moving the correct answer check mark, as the old answer is from the prehistory of Ethereum.

Answer (score 8):

Thomas from [Oraclize](http://oraclize.it) here.

One simple yet quite secure way to get a Bitcoin reference price into your contract is to use existing exchanges as datasources thanks to their APIs. I suppose here that what you want is BTCUSD, if it was BTCETH instead than minor code changes are required but the same reasoning applies.

Doing that in Solidity via Oraclize is trivial, I would suggest not to rely on a single exchange only, but for simplicity reasons the example that follows is using just one (Kraken).

I think the following code is self explanatory, but in case you have any questions feel free to ask here or via our support channels ([gitter](http://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api), email, ..).

```
/*
   Kraken-based ETH/USD price ticker

   This contract keeps in storage an updated ETH/USD price,
   which is optionally updated every ~60 seconds.
*/

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract KrakenPriceTicker is usingOraclize {

    uint public ETHUSD;

    event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newKrakenPriceTicker(string price);

    function KrakenPriceTicker() {
        // FIXME: enable oraclize_setProof is production
        // oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
        update(0);
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result, bytes proof) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        newKrakenPriceTicker(result);
        ETHUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // save it in storage as $ cents
        // do something with ETHUSD
        // update(60); // FIXME: comment this out to enable recursive price updates
    }

    function update(uint delay) payable {
        if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
        } else {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            oraclize_query(delay, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHUSD).result.XETHZUSD.c.0");
        }
    }

}
```

You can see this in [action here thanks to the Oraclize browser-solidity integration](http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#gist=fd46b7ab343be0034544aeb82b12f6b8), just click on the link and click on the contract "Create" button on the panel you find on the right!

[image: Oraclize Kraken Price Ticker Example]

Comment: What additional exchanges do you recommend? And do you recommend taking a median value? Or, alternatively, say the highest ask (if buying) or lowest bid (if selling)?

Comment: At that link, I don't see a "create" button on the panel to the right. I only see several error messages.